# In an ASP.NET View, how do I access my Model's values in Razor and assign it to a variable?

Tags: razor, view, asp.net-core-2.0

In my view I have

```
@model Models.ViewModel.MyViewModel
```

I can get the values displayed with the `Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.my_id)` method.  This works fine.

But I cannot get the value of a field in the model by doing anything like

```
int id = model.my_id;
```

Every time I use "`model`," Visual Studio cannot find a reference to it.  It does for the Html Helpers, but not when model is not in an Extension method like in the HtmlHelper (I thought it was an Extension Method).

I have tried many variations and various solutions I found on SO.  I am missing something fundamental, but I cannot find the answer of how to get the reference to model and its values.

It is also causing this to fail,

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = model.my_id })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Model` with a capital M.

```
@{
    int id = Model.my_id;
}

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.my_id })
```

Comment: You just thought you did ;-)

Comment: Yes.  It worked.  I can't make you the answer until 10 minutes goes by.  Thanks.